# Why is the graph of CMB/black-body radiation asymptotic?

Tags: cosmology, radiation, big-bang, cosmic-microwave-background, blackbody

Speaking of this graph of blackbody radiation, I see that the graph goes to 0 asymptotically:

[image: As the temperature decreases, the peak of the black-body radiation curve moves to lower intensities and longer wavelengths. The black-body radiation graph is also compared with the classical model of Rayleigh and Jeans.]

As we go to higher and higher frequencies, the energy of a single photon becomes increasingly high. Wouldn't there exist a point when the energy of a single photon is too large, and so there would be zero radiance at that frequency?

I am currently reading "The Inflationary Universe" by Alan Guth who introduces this blackbody graph and subsequently the motivation for photons by way of an analogy of visiting a bank to open an account but discovering the minimum deposit is larger than you have so you must leave without doing anything. I had thought I understood this analogy to mean that at arbitrarily high frequencies, the energy cost to emit a photon in that frequency exceeds the thermal energy of the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black body radiation is a statistical description i.e. it assumes there are enough photons that they are distributed according to Boltzmanns law. At energies high enough for a single photon to equal the total energy of the system this assumption breaks down and the black body description will no longer apply.

But by the point the energy has got this high the intensity predicted from the black body description will be so low as to be indistinguishable from zero, so this isn't a serious limitation.